# Return value from Oracle function call returns null

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, odp.net

I'm trying to call an Oracle function from our C# application, but it returns `{null}` instead of a number.

The function just does a `COUNT(*)` and `RETURNS` just that number. Now when I try and call it from the C# side, I always get `{null}` for the `cmd.Parameters["RowCount"].Value` of it. It's not just `null` but looks like an empty object with `null` as a value.

This is what it looks like from the C# side.

```
OracleCommand cmd = null;

try
{
    cmd = new OracleCommand("pack_Ams_ActivityChange.func_ActivitySearchRowCount", this.Connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("RowCount", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("FromDate", OracleDbType.Date, DateTime.Now(), ParameterDirection.Input));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ThruDate", OracleDbType.Date, DateTime.Now().AddDays(1), ParameterDirection.Input));

    int activityRowCount = 0;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Errors here since .Value is {null}
    activityRowCount = ((OracleDecimal)cmd.Parameters["RowCount"].Value).ToInt32();

    return activityRowCount;
}
```

This is what the function looks like on the database.

```
FUNCTION func_RowCount
(
 in_FromDate         IN DATE,
 in_ThruDate         IN DATE
) RETURN NUMBER AS
 lvnCount            NUMBER;
 lvsSqlStr           VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN

    lvsSqlStr := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE StartDate > :in_FromDate AND StartDate < :in_ThruDate';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lvsSqlStr INTO lvnCount USING in_FromDate, in_ThruDate;

    RETURN lvnCount;
END func_RowCount;
```

Comment: The problem here is on the C# side. The count(*) in oracle returns at least the number 0 and always a number >= 0. May be, the code, just intercepts the 0 and interprets it as {null}, this might depend on the ODP, but I'm pretty sure that's it. You can try and compare that to `System.DBNull`, I bet they will never be equal, unless there's something that intercepts the zero as a return code and makes it `{null}`.

Comment: @g00dy Yes, Comparing it to `null` or even `DBNull.Value` results in `false`.

Comment: Now that we know that it is different than `NULL`, we need to figure out if only the 0 values get transformed to this `{null}`. In order to do that, just make that pl/sql function `return 1` and then make it `return -1`. After you do this return here and paste the results.

Answer (score 1):

I have found odd results and behaviour with Oracle number formats and .NET type conversions - especially when using the `NUMBER` format without any precision.  I usually cast the value to an OracleDecimal and use its built it `.IsNull` function as opposed to trying to use .NET `DbNull.Value`'s etc.

```
var temporaryResult = new OracleDecimal(cmd.Parameters["RowCount"].Value);
activityRowCount = temporaryResult.IsNull ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(temporaryResult.Value);
```

Still unsure why its returning null anyway!

Comment: Just thinking about this, have you tried accessing the Parameters collection by element `[0]` and not the name?

Answer (score 0):

You need only:

```
FUNCTION func_RowCount
(
 in_FromDate         IN DATE,
 in_ThruDate         IN DATE
) RETURN NUMBER AS
 lvnCount            NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
     INTO lvnCount 
     FROM SomeTable 
     WHERE StartDate > in_FromDate 
     AND StartDate < in_ThruDate;
    RETURN lvnCount;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  RETURN 0;
END func_RowCount;
```

With such EXCEPTION you will get guaranteed number even if your SELECT somehow returns null. EXECUTE and bind variables are not needed at all.

Also, as this is a function, you can return its result as a usual select, no need to call it like a stored proc.
Something like this will do the trick:

```
cmd = new OracleCommand("select pack_Ams_ActivityChange.func_ActivitySearchRowCount(?,?) from dual", this.Connection);
```

Comment: do we need no_data_found exception for count?

Comment: count(*) returns 0 even if your table is empty

Comment: You're right, it's not obligatory in this example. It's just a good practice.